# AVERAGEIFS Excel Formula Incorporated With Dates

Tags: excel, average

so I have an excel file with 2 tabs. 1 tab lists some values for Aug - Dec 2019 is separate columns while the other tab is the average of every 3 months (ie: Aug - Oct 2019, Sept - Nov 2019, Oct - Dec 2019).

[image: Click Here for Tab 1]

[image: Click Here for Tab 2]

I am trying to create a formula to give me the average of 3 months (listed in tab 1) **if** the KRI_ID column (in column A) is the same.

**Note:** Dates are input in custom format (mmm-yy)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need an `Averageif` formula, since the `KRI_ID` is unique to each row. You can simply enter the following formula in cell `J2` and drag across then drag down from J2 for the rest of the rows:

`=Average(J2:L2)`

Comment: Ye but if the order of the IDs in both tabs are different, then will this not show the incorrect average?

Comment: Yes but your diagrams show them in the same order? If not id suggest you put the data in the same order to simplify your calculation.

Comment: They won't always be in the same order. If any new IDs are entered, the calculations will be wrong.

Comment: Ok, so are row 4 and 13 not percentages?

Comment: Also note that In AVERAGEIFS, each criteria range must be the same size and shape as the range you want to average